# Suppressing page numbers for some entries in glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I am using the glossaries package.

I want to suppress the page number for some items in my glossaries.
I know `printglossary`'s `nonumberlist` option suppresses 
page numbers for all items.

Is there a simple way (like setting a key for the item) 
to suppress page numbers for a specific item?

Answer (score 2):

`nonumberlist` can also be added to items. E.g.

```
\newglossaryentry{ex}{%
  name={Example},%
  description={An example},%
  nonumberlist,%
}%
```